# Can't set data usage warning/limit

Tags: mobile-data

I have a problem with my Nexus 5 (running Android 5.0 but I already had this problem on 4.4.4)

I played around with the slider for mobile data limits and warnings and it got out of range... My warning now is at 719.806.528 GB and my data limit is also out of range. 
Does someone know which app's cache do I have to delete to get this to 0 GB again?

Thanks and best regards

Josef

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing defaults, cache and data(memory) for the dataUsage app.

You could also simply uncheck the "set mobile data limit button" except you really need to use it. You can also try returning the slider to zero.

Comment: I can't grab the sliders and the problem is, that I can't see the graph for the data usage (except if mobile data is of). And It would be nice if I have a visulisation of my data usage :/